# Recieving an array in VB.NET from a php (NuSOAP) web service

Tags: php, arrays, vb.net, web-services, nusoap

I have successfully managed to run many php (NuSOAP) web services from VB.NET, however I am unable return an array without the following error:

> "There is an error in XML document (1, x)."

For the following three instances, I am able to get it working from php to php (NuSOAP), but from VB.NET to php(NuSOAP), it always returns the above error. These are the three examples.

```
xsd:Array

$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
 'ArrayOfString',
 'complexType',
 'array',
 'sequence',
 '',
 array(
  'itemName' => array(
   'name' => 'itemName',
   'type' => 'xsd:string',
   'minOccurs' => '0',
   'maxOccurs' => 'unbounded'
  )
 )
);

$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
 'Users',
 'complexType',
 'struct',
 'all',
 '',
 array( 'Users' => array('name' => 'UsersIn',
   'type' => 'xsd:Array'))
);
```

Is this a limitation, or is there something else I can do? Thanks

---

Edit:
OK, I've searched far and wide for this issue and seen so many that have tried to solve it but none succeed. It appears to be a.NET issue possibly due to php communication, so I would rule out NuSOAP because I hardcoded the same thing in pure php and it resulted in the same problem.

I have also looked at the xml files returned by SOAP and they all validated while the error locations were in pretty harmless locations. I think possibly the xml file it is looking at may not actually be the one returned by SOAP but something else or otherwise recently serialized, the reference is, 'System.Xml.dll'.

I also played around with some basic encoding on the database and SOAP server but that didn't change the result.

Comment: See recent edit for ruling out NuSOAP as the source of the issue.